# Componentes web para pesquisa de dados do banco

Tags: javascript, c#, webforms

Estou fazendo um pequeno sistema de cadastro de itens de produtos.

Como vim do Delphi estava procurando uma forma de carregar os produtos por código ou pelo nome em um Dropdownlist.

Estive pesquisando e vi um sistema que estava utilizando um componente como eu queria, onde o usuário pesquisa pelo código ou pelo nome e é carregado a informação no Dropdownlist.

Alguém poderia me dar dicas de como fazer isso?

Comment: Você procura pelo [Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)?

Comment: Algo do tio, eu um exemplo utilizando o autocomplete jquery, eu achei que aquelo componente do video (um textbox de codigo , colado em um textbox de nome) seria um componente, como vim do delphi , acho que estou confundido aquilo pode ser um css da vida pelo que estive pesquisando

Answer (score 0):

Você pode passar o parâmetro para sua query que popula o DropDrownlist:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource id="Prod" runat="server"
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myBase %>"
  SelectCommand="SELECT ColunaID, ColunaText FROM Tabela
                 WHERE ParametroFiltro= @ParametroFiltro">

  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ID" QueryStringField="ParametroFiltro" />
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```